# Javascript add event listers for all checkboxes inside a class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add event listers for all checkboxes inside a class. I am able to add event listener to class. How can I add to all checkboxes inside that class?

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");

var myFunction = function() {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
    alert(attribute);
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since JS events [bubble up to parent elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) you only have to attach ONE event listener to the parent element and it will catch every event triggered by its children.

```js
document.querySelector('#container').onclick = function(ev) {
  if(ev.target.value) {
    console.log(ev.target.checked, ev.target.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Car">I have a car<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Flower">I have a flower<br>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure? sounds very interesting?

Comment: @Kurkula yes I'm sure, and yes it is :) 
I provided a link to another SO question talking about it, if you want to read some more.

Comment: @Kurkula, this is the preferred approach as 1) bubbling is how the DOM works 2) it saves you having all those event listeners, 3) If you decided to add a checkbox dynamically to the page, the function would still work even if you didn't specifically attach a listener to it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `querySelectorAll`

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll( '.example input[type=checkbox]' );

var myFunction = function() {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
    console.log( attribute );
};

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <input type="checkbox" data-myattribute="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-myattribute="2" />
</div>
```

---

Or you could just use the `event.target` property of your old event listener like this:

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

var myFunction = function(event) {
  var attribute = event.target.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
  console.log(attribute);
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
  classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <input type="checkbox" data-myattribute="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-myattribute="2" />
</div>
```

Of course, with the second approach you need to check, if you really deal with a checkbox.

---

**In your case though I would rather use change events instead of click. That way, you can use it within a label and have the label clickable, instead of only the checkbox itself.**

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll( '.example input[type=checkbox]' );

var myFunction = function( event ) {
    var attribute = event.target.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
    console.log( attribute );
};

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-myattribute="1" /> test1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-myattribute="2" /> test2
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to. Just check the `event.target` to see if a checkbox was clicked.

```
var myFunction = function(event) {
    if (event.target.type === "checkbox") {
      var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
      alert(attribute);  
    }
};
```

Also, there's shorter syntax available for getting data attribute values.

```
var attribute = this.dataset.myattribute;
```

You also probably want a `change` event rather than a `click` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll`
This `document.querySelectorAll(".classname input[type='checkbox']");` will select the parent element by it's class and then the child `inputs`

```js
var classname = document.querySelectorAll(".classname input[type='checkbox']");
classname.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
    console.log(attribute);

  })
})
```

```html
<div class="classname">
  <input type="checkbox" data-myattribute="1">
  <input type="checkbox" data-myattribute="2">
  <input type="checkbox" data-myattribute="3">
  <input type="checkbox" data-myattribute="4">

</div>
```